# How can I avoid setting actual jdbc connection with Hibernate during my test run?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jdbc

Actually I am writing kind of sdk which can be used for mocking my database queries. For that I have implemented my custom driver and making it register with the Hibernate.

So basically I first created data mocks of the SQL object and saved that in a yaml files (Encoded form).
Then at the time of testing I just want to use that data mocks which I captured earlier , But this time I don't want my connection Open i.e I want to replicate my test environment without making actual database calls then I will be performing further queries by reading and decoding stored objects .

So I am having problem with connect method -

```
  @Override
    public Connection connect(String url, Properties info) {
        if (Objects.equals(System.getenv("SDK_MODE"), "test")){
            return new MyConnection();
        }
        Connection resultSet = null;
        try {
            result = wrappedDriver.connect(url, info);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return new MyConnection(result);

    }
```

I was trying to send empty connection but since DriverDatasource.getconnection() method of `javax.sql` package sends new connection (Hikari Pool base) and verifies if connection is live I am getting exceptions like -

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: null
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: null
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:596) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:582) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext.getQueryResults(ExtractionContext.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.initializeSequences(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.<init>(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.Helper.buildDatabaseInformation(Helper.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1498) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.my.ksql.KConnection.isReadOnly(KConnection.java:130) ~[my-sdk-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setupConnection(PoolBase.java:408) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

**So Is there any way I can skip establishing connection part during test using ORM (Hibernate) and directly take my control flow to `PreparedStatement` so that I can get my mocked sql objects back and replay my queries for performing tests**

Comment: I dont understand your requirements, but you could look into the annotation @TestConfiguration to have custom configuration for just your tests, or if this is not only Test Specific, but you want the application to act/connect differently , then look into using profiles

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that what you are trying is not really the best way to do.

We need definitly more information, because my first reaction is to say that you are trying to mock way to "low level" here.

Why do you need to mock the connection? You can spawn a fake DB via Testcontainers. Then you can execute some actual tests on a real db.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer!

Comment: My answer is that he should use Testcontainers to fake a DB